# MySQL JOIN -> Get all data from right table even if there is no match

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

I have two tables, one with **data (A)** and other with **categories (B)** which is in one of those categories or uncategorized. I need to make simple stats, so I am using JOIN to get all data from table A and join it with table B.

What I need is, that even if there is no match in A, I want to show all categories from B on graph (with count = 0, but I need them to be shown).

So if there are no items with that category id, it does not show that category at all, but I need to show it, even if it has 0 items.

I tried LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, both of them with UNION and nothing worked.

**Table A**

```
id | some | irrelevant | data | category
-----------------------------------------
1  |      |            |      | 0
2  |      |            |      | 0
3  |      |            |      | 1
4  |      |            |      | 2
5  |      |            |      | 3
6  |      |            |      | 3
. . . . . . . . . . .
```

**Table B**

```
id | title  | color
---------------------
1  | Cat 1  | #FFFFFF
2  | Cat 2  | #FF00FF
3  | Cat 3  | #FF0000
4  | Cat 4  | #00FF00
5  | Cat 5  | #00FFFF
6  | Cat 6  | #000000
7  | Cat 7  | #FFFF00
```

With those data I **want** to get something like:

```
Array ( [category] => 0 [count] => 3 [title] => [color] => ) 
Array ( [category] => 1 [count] => 1 [title] => Cat 1 [color] => #FFFFFF ) 
Array ( [category] => 2 [count] => 1 [title] => Cat 2 [color] => #FF00FF ) 
Array ( [category] => 3 [count] => 2 [title] => Cat 3 [color] => #FF0000 ) 
Array ( [category] => 4 [count] => 0 [title] => Cat 4 [color] => #00FF00 ) 
Array ( [category] => 5 [count] => 0 [title] => Cat 5 [color] => #00FFFF ) 
Array ( [category] => 6 [count] => 0 [title] => Cat 6 [color] => #000000 ) 
Array ( [category] => 7 [count] => 0 [title] => Cat 7 [color] => #FFFF00 )
```

But thats what I **actually** get:

```
Array ( [category] => 0 [count] => 3 [title] => [color] => ) 
Array ( [category] => 1 [count] => 1 [title] => Cat 1 [color] => #FFFFFF ) 
Array ( [category] => 2 [count] => 1 [title] => Cat 2 [color] => #FF00FF ) 
Array ( [category] => 3 [count] => 2 [title] => Cat 3 [color] => #FF0000 )
```

This is the **call**:

```
"SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS count, title, color FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.id=A.category GROUP BY category"
```

PS.: Once more, I trued RIGHT join too and UNION of RIGHT and LEFT join.
Also, the names of tables are really long, cant really use them in call as A.category etc.

Is there some way to do that without using two SQL calls and two loops? I really don't want to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: I did google for couple hours... I never ask without using Google first, as I hate when somebody does that.

Comment: So, based on the data you have provided, if you join these tables the only category that won't have a match would be `Cat 7` since there is no `id = 7` in categories table, right? I don't understand where the output table you have provided comes from..

Comment: no, I am matching them by A.category=B.id :) And that output table is what I want, not what I get.

Comment: That was the typo when i was writing a code here, its actually B.id=A.category.. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a70711/8)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
    (`id` int, `category` int)
;

INSERT INTO TableA
    (`id`, `category`)
VALUES
    (1, 0),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 3),
    (6, 3)
;

CREATE TABLE TableB
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(5), `color` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO TableB
    (`id`, `title`, `color`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Cat 1', '#FFFFFF'),
    (2, 'Cat 2', '#FF00FF'),
    (3, 'Cat 3', '#FF0000'),
    (4, 'Cat 4', '#00FF00'),
    (5, 'Cat 5', '#00FFFF'),
    (6, 'Cat 6', '#000000'),
    (7, 'Cat 7', '#FFFF00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TableB.id as category, count(distinct TableA.id) as count,title,color
FROM
(SELECT * FROM TableB
UNION
SELECT 0 as id, '' as title, '' as color) AS TableB
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA on TableB.id = TableA.category
GROUP BY TableB.id, title, color
ORDER BY TableB.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a70711/8/0)**:

```
| CATEGORY | COUNT | TITLE |   COLOR |
|----------|-------|-------|---------|
|        0 |     2 |       |         |
|        1 |     1 | Cat 1 | #FFFFFF |
|        2 |     1 | Cat 2 | #FF00FF |
|        3 |     2 | Cat 3 | #FF0000 |
|        4 |     0 | Cat 4 | #00FF00 |
|        5 |     0 | Cat 5 | #00FFFF |
|        6 |     0 | Cat 6 | #000000 |
|        7 |     0 | Cat 7 | #FFFF00 |
```

Also, instead of using `UNION SELECT 0 as id, '' as title, '' as color`, you can add a category with id 0 in your TableB

Comment: ^^THIS^^ **WORKS** :) About the 0 category, Yeah I was thinking about it, but IDK why, but when I tried to INSERT to DB an item with ID 0, it just set it as ID 1, if there wer IE 6 items, it set it to be ID 7... So I just set Title, and Color manualy in your Query.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**
Adding both create data SQL and the SQL query below to prove the data:

To Add Test Data run the following SQL commands:

```
DROP TABLE junk_category;

CREATE TABLE junk_category (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO junk_category (id,name) VALUES (1,'Cat 1'), (2,'Cat 2'), (3, 'Cat 3'), (4, 'Cat 4');

DROP TABLE junk_data;

CREATE TABLE junk_data (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    category INT NULL,
    INDEX byCategory (category)
);

INSERT INTO junk_data (id, name, category)
VALUES
(1,'one',1),
(2,'two',1),
(3,'three',1),
(4,'four',2),
(5,'five',2),
(6,'six',3),
(7,'seven',NULL),
(8,'eight',NULL);
```

To Query Test Data:

```
SELECT 'Uncategorized' AS category, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM junk_data A
    WHERE A.category IS NULL
UNION
SELECT B.name AS category, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) AS count
    FROM junk_category B
    LEFT JOIN junk_data A ON A.category=B.id
    GROUP BY category
```

The only change needed from the query I had given you before was the DISTINCT A.id.  I missed that in the previous paste I had done. Without the DISTINCT A.id, the category itself counts as 1.  The DISTINCT limits it to the data table.  However, you said you were seeing 3...but the query doesn't "copy" and it wouldn't be 3 where it should be none...so if you are seeing 3 where there should be none, there is some other issue.

**[UPDATE 2015-03-03]**

If you are not getting all your categories from this query:

```
SELECT B.name AS category, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) AS count
    FROM junk_category B
    LEFT JOIN junk_data A ON A.category=B.id
    GROUP BY category
```

There is only one reason that this wouldn't return all your categories: **if they are not uniquely named**. The only filter in the above is the `GROUP BY`.

However, I realize that I may have confused you because I am naming `B.name AS category` which is the name of one of your columns.  The `GROUP BY` is really `GROUP BY B.name`. Thus, the only way to lose any entries is if they have the same `B.name`.  So, in any case, your `GROUP BY` needs to be on your B table, not your A table.

**There is not much else I can do without seeing your actual query** and seeing if your GROUP BY or WHERE are placing additional restrictions. Or utilize my install-junk sql and make sure you can get the same results and then try to figure out the differences between my queries and what your actual queries are doing.

Comment: I dont really understand your answer... The Uncategorized if only for me, its not in TB, basically I just assign categories to the data that has category and if its 0 I just print that as uncategorized. So basically, in DB A there is category thats set to 0 (if no category selected), or one of categories IDs. If you know what I mean.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB, You can make it the string "uncategorized" as I did, or just do `NULL AS category`...whatever tickles your fancy.  The only rule in UNIONs is that the columns must match on both sides, so you must do something as the placeholder.  The second query does NOT work, I was using that to show that the UNION is required.  I created a structure similar to yours and tested these queries against it, and only the UNION returns your desired data.

Comment: Trust me I tried it and it does not work. It returns only the categories that have some match in other table. The empty ones are not returned.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question so you can clearly see what exactly I want this to return and what I am getting (not with your code tho. Your code gives me Uncategorized = 3 but then also first category that has no items and sets the count on it to 3. Baiscally sets Uncategorized correctly and then finds empty category and palces all uncategorized results to that too. And also, it does not show any other categories that have no items.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB, the only thing I'd missed was putting the DISTINCT on A.id. That would cause the category itself to count as 1 where there should be none...but it would not add 3. However, to avoid any further problems, I posted both the working test data and working test-query.

Comment: Trust me that it does not work. I just tried it and it does not work. Im adding exact result of your code to my question. Gimme a sec. Its there.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB, trust me, if you are using my query with synonymous columns and GROUP BY, it does work **unless you have categories with the same name** or **misunderstood the `GROUP BY`**, which I've explained in an update on my answer.

Comment: I added exact query to my question I am using, so you can see what I mean. It never returns me those empty ones. Might be that I am just not really getting what you want from me, but I am copying your query, so...

Answer (score 0):

> This answer is not the best variant, but I want to provide it in case
>   nobody here knows how to do what I want with single query and loop.

---

Right know I "solved" it with while loops (which is exactly what I did not want to use), but it actually looks like what I want is impossible...

```
$get_stats = dbquery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, category FROM XXX GROUP BY category");
$get_cats = dbquery("SELECT * FROM YYYYY");
$categories = array();
$stats_arr = array();

while ($cat = dbarray($get_cats)){
    $categories[$cat['id']] = array($cat['title'], $cat['color']);
    $stats_arr[$cat['id']] = array('count' => 0, 'title' => $cat['title'], 'color' => $cat['color']);
}

while ($stats = dbarray($get_stats)){
    if ($stats['category'] === "0"){
        $stats_arr[0] = array('count' => $stats['count'], 'title' => 'Uncategorized', 'color' => '#FFFFFF');
    }else{
        $stats_arr[$stats['category']] = array('count' => $stats['count'], 'title' => $categories[$stats['category']][0], 'color' => $categories[$stats['category']][1]);
    }
}
ksort($stats_arr);

foreach ($stats_arr as $id => $data) {
    // Code here
}
```

I still want to make it work without need for all of those loops tho.

Its OK for now, as its on a page where I already was looping trough categories, but it still added 2 loops and I want to use it on separate page, so I need to solve it with single query + loop.